# error: no matching function for call to

Tags: c++

I am getting the "no matching function for call to error" in my code.  The code is creating instances of one class in the constructor of another class.

The code is as follows:

```
inline DiscriminatorContainer::DiscriminatorContainer(ushort id, FebPtr feb):
 m_id(id), m_feb(feb), m_discriminators(new Discriminators())   {
    //make discriminators
    for (ushort i = 0; i <kNDiscriminators; ++i){
        DiscriminatorPtr dsc = DiscriminatorPtr(new Discriminator(i, this));
        m_discriminators->push_back(dsc);

    }
}

inline Discriminator::Discriminator(ushort id, DiscriminatorContainerPtr dc, double threshold) :
    m_id(id), m_threshold(threshold),
    m_nhits(0), m_dc(dc) 
  {
    init();
  }
```

These constructors are actually in two different header files, but I included both for completeness.

I get the error

```
../src/DiscriminatorContainer.h:50: error: no matching function for call to `Minerva::Discriminator::Discriminator(ushort&, Minerva::DiscriminatorContainer* const)'
../src/Discriminator.h:24: note: candidates are: Minerva::Discriminator::Discriminator(const Minerva::Discriminator&)
../src/Discriminator.h:61: note:                 Minerva::Discriminator::Discriminator(ushort, Minerva::DiscriminatorContainerPtr, double)
```

about the line that goes `DiscriminatorPtr dsc = ....`

I know that such an error usually means I've got a wrong data type somewhere, but I can't figure out where it could be?

Comment: What is the definition of `DiscriminatorContainerPtr`? You're passing a raw pointer (`this`) as the constructor argument that expects one of them.

Comment: DiscriminatorContainerPtr is defined to be a pointer to a class DiscriminatorContainer.  It's defined in yet another header file...

Answer (score 6):

Typical case of "read the error message more carefully".

It's telling you that you are trying to call the function with the signature `Minerva::Discriminator::Discriminator(ushort&, Minerva::DiscriminatorContainer* const)`

but there only exists two other constructors

```
Minerva::Discriminator::Discriminator(const Minerva::Discriminator&)
Minerva::Discriminator::Discriminator(ushort, Minerva::DiscriminatorContainerPtr, double)
```

So just check the call to the constructor. You probably forget one argument.

Answer (score 1):

`new Discriminator(i, this)` does not match any constructors.

---

**Edit**

Well, [inlining doesn't affect default arguments](http://codepad.org/gGCtOrt2) so you must have made a mistake somewhere else!

Comment: Right, okay, but why does it not match any constructors?  The 3rd parameter goes to a default, and as far as I can tell, I've matched the first two parameters with a ushort and a pointer.

Comment: @Mary - We can't see any default value in the code. Can the compiler see it?

Comment: I wonder whether the `inline` keyword has a part to play here.

Comment: Nope, you're going to have to present a testcase because [this works fine](http://codepad.org/gGCtOrt2).

Comment: The default is set in the Discriminator.h header file:
Discriminator(ushort id, DiscriminatorContainerPtr dc,  double threshold = 100);  ///< constructor
I seem to think that the problem could be that apparently I'm giving a ushort& rather than a ushort, but I don't know where in my code I'm making that mistake?  As far as I can tell, I'm feeding the constructor a ushort, not anything else?