# Having a string within a system()

Tags: c++, string, system

How can I use a string within a system().
ex: (input is the string)

```
system("open -a Google Chrome" "http://www.dictionary.reference.com/browse/" + input + "?s=t");
```

Because when I do this I get this error (No matching function for call to 'system').

Comment: include stdlib.h And system() takes a char*, not a std::string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[system](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/system/) is available in `cstdlib` header.

Function takes a c-style string as a parameter. `+` doesn't append string literals.

So try -

```
std::string cmd("open -a Google Chrome");
cmd += " http://www.dictionary.reference.com/browse/" + input + "?s=t";

// In the above case, operator + overloaded in `std::string` is called and 
// does the necessary concatenation.

system(cmd.c_str());
```

Comment: Did you actually try that?  What data type are you assuming for `input`?  If it's `std::string`, his existing code will work for concatenation.

Comment: @BenVoigt I was trying to avoid addition on two [string literals](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c6305349f287715c). However, the first two string literals can be combined to one in OP case though.

Comment: Not only can be, his question uses the right syntax to make the compiler combine them.

Answer (score -1):

Have you included the `stdlib` header?

`No matching function for call to 'system'` typically occurs when it cannot resolve a function with that signature.

EG:

```
#include <stdlib.h> // Needed for system().

int main()
{
    system("some argument"); 
    return 1;
}
```

And don't forget to `.c_str()` your std::string variable when passing it in as an argument.

See:

1. [`system()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/system) documentation.
2. [This SO answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6667342/error-no-matching-function-for-call-to)